# placing blocks beside each other in Drupal

Tags: css, drupal, drupal-7, block, inline

I made three new blocks in Drupal and want to place them in the same region and this all three next each other ( or beside each other).

I added the blocks in the style.css file like this.

```css
#block-views-name_of_view {
 float:left;
 }
 
 #block-views-name_of_view2 {
 float:left;
 }
 #block-views-name_of_view3 {
 float:left;
 }
```

And nothing happened :)
Did I place them in a wrong place in the file?
Is this not enough?
I am kinda lost.

Can you help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure your parent container holding those blocks has a fixed width of say 1000px and each of those blocks give it a width of 200px and that should do it.